# Solve $ x^2 + xy + y^2 = \left( \frac{x+y}{3}+1 \right)^2 $ in integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve in integers $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ the equation:
$$ x^2 + xy + y^2 = \left( \frac{x+y}{3}+1 \right)^2 $$
Could we solve this using lattice reduction?

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Simplifying your given equation we get
$$8x^2+7xy+8y^2-6x-6y-9=0$$
solving this equation for $y$ and considering the discriminat we get
$$-23x^2+12x+36\geq 0$$ this is only fulfilled for $$x=-1,x=0,x=1$$